# How to add json data in a combobox column using c#?

Tags: c#, json

This is my dummy json file.I want to display name and mapped_name in datagridview.Mapped_name is a combobox column.So suppose when the name column contains button the mapped_name column should contain a combox box having options linklabel and button.

```
{"components":[
       {
       "id":"1",
       "name":"Button",
       "mapped_name":[
              {"id":"1",
               "name":"LinkLabel"
               },
               {"id":"2",
               "name":"Button"
               }
               ]


       },
       {
       "id":"2",
       "name":"ListView",
       "mapped_name":[
              {"id":"1",
               "name":"TabView"
               },
               {"id":"2",
               "name":"ListView"
               },
               {"id":"3",
               "name":"Tiles"
               }
               ]


       }
```

Comment: Which UI technology do you use? Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, other?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse the data and display it. You can use [JsonTextReader](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) class

See the [samples here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm) also check [help](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)